Filter the Earliest and Latest Date in Each Month
Given a dataframe like the one below, how do I filter for the earlest and latest date in each month? Note the actual data runs to tens of thousands of rows.
Input:



Date
Deg




02/01/1990
1210.92


13/01/1990
1226.83


14/01/1990
1224.52


15/01/1990
1220.77


08/02/1990
1164.32


09/02/1990
1156.72


12/02/1990
1145.18


13/02/1990
1146.88


24/02/1990
1149.07



Desired output:



Date
Deg




02/01/1990
1210.92


15/01/1990
1220.77


08/02/1990
1164.32


24/02/1990
1149.07




show your attempt to get the answer

Please read How to make good reproducible pandas examples - the easier it is for us to construct the dataframe, the more answers your question will get.

Your data looks sorted. Try this:
df["year"] = df["Date"].dt.year
df["month"] = df["Date"].dt.month
return pd.concat(
  [
    df.groupby(["month", "year"]).last(),
    df.groupby(["month", "year"]).first()
  ]
).reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(by="Date")

